# How to pass multiple data from child to parent component in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to pass "event" as well as event's "pick" value to service to later use those in another component.
I'm not sure how to get child's "pick" value from ngFor scope to parent component and if that's even possible or is there another way of doing so?

Just started learning Angular so if I'm doing something wrong here let me know, I'd appreciate it!

events.component.html

```
<div class="league" *ngFor="let league of events.locations[0].leagues">
  <h1>{{ league.name }}</h1>
  <div class="events" *ngFor="let eventsByDay of league.eventDateGroups">
    <div class="day-market">
      <p class="date">{{ eventsByDay.date | date :'mediumDate' }}</p>
      <div class="main-markets">
        <p>1</p>
        <p>x</p>
        <p>2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <app-event *ngFor="let event of eventsByDay.events"
      [event]="event"
      [eventsByDay]="eventsByDay"
      (onAddToTicket)="addToTicket(event)"></app-event>
  </div>
</div>
```

events.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EventsService } from 'src/app/services/events.service';
import { TicketService } from 'src/app/services/ticket.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-events',
  templateUrl: './events.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./events.component.scss']
})
export class EventsComponent implements OnInit {
  events: any = [];

  constructor(
    private eventsService: EventsService, 
    private ticketService: TicketService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.eventsService.getEvents().subscribe(events => this.events = events);
  }

  addToTicket(event: any) {
    this.ticketService.addToTicket(event);
  }
}
```

event.component.html

```
<ul class="events-by-day">
  <li class="event">
    <div class="event-info">
      <h3>{{ event.fixture.participants[0].name }} | 
        {{ event.fixture.participants[1].name }}</h3>
      <p>{{ event.fixture.startDate | date :'shortTime' }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="markets" *ngFor="let market of event.markets | filter: 1">
      <p class="pick" *ngFor="let pick of market.picks"
        (click)="onQuotaClick(event)" >
        {{ market.marketId == 1 ? pick.odds : ''}}</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

event.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-event',
  templateUrl: './event.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./event.component.scss']
})
export class EventComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() event: any;
  @Input() eventsByDay: any;
  @Output() onAddToTicket: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onQuotaClick(event: any) {
    this.onAddToTicket.emit(event);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can.

The most straightforward way is to emit an object wrapping the `event` and the `pick`.

Like, in the HTML:

```html
(click)="onQuotaClick({event: event, pick: pick})"
```

And propagate this type `{event:any; pick: any}` all the way up in the different functions.

*Also note that you should not use `any` but actual types, otherwise you loose all the safety that Typescript brings you.*

Comment: Thank you man! So basically EvenEmitter can only take one parametar, in this case an object.
Yeah, I'll fix that just wanted to see how everything works, I'm also new to TypeScript, it's really amazing.

Comment: Exactly. You could have several event emitters though but in your case it's one event with multiple data.